# Laravel Call to undefined method issue

Tags: php, laravel

I keep getting an error:

> Call to undefined method App\Facebook::fbLogin()** when
>   **handleProviderCallback()

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Facebook;

class FacebookController extends Controller
{
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        $route = Facebook::fbLogin($user);
        return redirect()->route($route);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace App;
class Facebook extends Model
{
    public static function fbLogin($user){
         .......
    }
}
```

Already spent hours looking for a solution. Please help.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Can you share the **exact** code and  error lines throwing that error?

Comment: thank you guys.
I delete everything and restart and now it works.

When I generated the model, it was in lowercase 'facebook.php' so I renamed the file to 'Facebook.php'. I think it's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the model and recreate it again. maybe some kind of indexing issue. other than this run following command in the composer. 
composer dump-autoload